# How to use react Rollup index.js file in angular project

Tags: reactjs, angular, rollup

I have react project with Rollup config.js file and i am able to generate rollup bundle file. when i try to put it inside angular project got error like this

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react/jsx-runtime". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".